# How do I figure out what to set my DISPLAY variable to for a virtual display?

Tags: linux, display, xvfb

Here's my `uname -a` info ...

```
Linux qa3398c 2.6.18-194.8.1.el5 #1 SMP Wed Jun 23 10:52:51 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm running some Google Web toolkit tests that require access to a virtual display.  I don't know what to set my DISPLAY environment variable to get that functionality.  I've tried things like `"localhost:0.0"`, `":0.0"` and `"0.0"`, but all result in errors like

> Caused by: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect 
>   to X11 window server using 'localhost:0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY 
>   variable.

How do I figure out what to set my DISPLAY variable to?  I have Xvfb installed on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

X has an authentication mechanism, which decides whether a client is allowed to connect to a server

Without know other details such as the user trying to access X, I can't be as specific with this answer as I would generally like, but you can try this and see if it works:

```
xhost +localhost
```

From man page:
The  xhost  program  is used to add and delete host names or user names to the list allowed to make connections to the X server. In the case of hosts, this provides a rudimentary form of privacy control and security. It is only sufficient for a workstation  (sin‐gle  user)  environment, although it does limit the worst abuses.  Environments which require more sophisticated measures should implement the user-based mechanism or use the hooks in the protocol for passing other authentication data to the server.

+  Access is granted to everyone, even if they aren't on the list (i.e., access control is turned off).